# Bash script copy *.log files into a new directory

Tags: unix

i got some files like this:

```
2012-12-17_083213_1.log
2012-12-17_083213_1.log_stats
2012-12-17_083213_1.logaccount_ptr
2012-12-17_083213_1.loginitial_ptr
2012-12-17_083213_1.logptr
2012-12-17_093049_2.log
2012-12-17_093049_2.log_stats
2012-12-17_093049_2.logaccount_ptr
2012-12-17_093049_2.loginitial_ptr
2012-12-17_093049_2.logptr
```

in here every 1G of data filled a new file is created with the name in Year-Month-Day_HourMinuteSecond_number.log format (as you can see above).
I want to

1. Copy all *.log to a new folder named with the format Year-Month-Day like for these it would be named 2012-12-17
2. Tgz that folder
3. Send it to a server IP.

I don't know how exactly. I want it as a bash script so that I can run it every day for the newly added files. Thanks for helping.

Comment: this may be a better fit down at [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *log ; do
    targetdir=${f:0:10}
    mkdir ${targetdir} 2>/dev/null
    echo ${targetdir} > dirstotar
    mv ${f} ${targetdir}
done 
sort dirstotar | uniq | while read dir ; do
    tar --remove-files -cvzf "${dir}.tar.gz" "${dir}"
done
find . -name '*tar.gz' -print | xargs scp '{}' user@host:/dir
```

This might work for you.

1. for every log file check its name, and creates a directory with the first 10 char of the log files name (if there's one, just ignore the error)
2. move the logfile to that dir
3. log the directory name to a file for later processing.
4. process the directory list (tar)
5. copy every tar.gz to remote host.

It's just a starting point for you. If you want a complete solution, show us what have you tried, what went wrong. Or hire a professional.

Comment: thank you so much but my question is that in here all *.log files are put in the new folder, what if i want all the files dated today to be put there? i mean in here i want 2012-12-17_083213 to be my folder and then inside it i have the .log and .log_stats and etc with this name inside it?